# how to get XML response from .net SOAP web services in java?

Tags: java, .net

I have a SOAP web services in .net application which return data through Data table. Whenever I am going to use this web service in java application I am getting reference from .net web service method which return Data table.

```
ASP .NET WEB SERVICE SAMPLE CODE
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
 {   [WebMethod]
    public DataTable ReturnTable()
    {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("user");
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("ID");
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);
            DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = "1";
            row[1] = "Jonh";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);

            DataRow row2 = dt.NewRow();
            row2[0] = "2";
            row2[1] = "David";
            dt.Rows.Add(row2);
            return dt;
           }}}
```

How to implement this SOAP service in java and get XML response.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a webservices client from the WSDL of .net webservice.  This will enable you to invoke the service and handle the data as methods and objects.

[Creating a Web Service Client](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/reference/tutorials/wsit/doc/Examples_glassfish6.html#wp107167)